# Laravel Delete Model only works in local environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having a strange behaviour with deleting model records. I have a table where I select records and I pass the ID's to a route for deleting them.
This works OK in local environment but in server environment is not working, I'm recieving the following exception message:**Class 'App\OfferDemand' not found**

It looks like in server environment, it's failing due to some array issue? 
Does anyone can help me?

Regards!

This is **local environment request** extracted from Telescope:

```
{
"ids": [
"6",
"5"
]
}
```

This is **server environment request** extracted from Telescope:

```
{
"ids": [
"3",
"2"
]
}
```

This is the Route:

```
Route::post('/processes/offerdemand/delete/', 'OfferDemandController@delete')->name('processes.offerdemand.delete')->middleware('auth');
```

This is the Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\OfferDemand;
use App\User;
use App\Property;
use SearchHelper;
use DB;

class OfferDemandController extends Controller
{

    public function delete(Request $request)
    {
        $ids = $request->ids;
        try {
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $offerdemanddelete = OfferDemand::findOrFail($id);
                $offerdemanddelete->offerdemandslocations()->delete();
                $offerdemanddelete->offerdemandsattributes()->delete();
                $offerdemanddelete->offerdemandsmatchs()->delete();
                $offerdemanddelete->delete();
            }

            return response()->json([
                'status' => 200
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 500,
                'message'  => $ex->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the AJAX call:

```
var selectedDelete = function () {
        $('#kt_subheader_group_actions_delete_all').on('click', function () {
            // fetch selected IDs
            var ids = [];
            var ids = datatable.rows('.kt-datatable__row--active').nodes().find('.kt-checkbox--single > [type="checkbox"]').map(function (i, chk) {
                return $(chk).val();

            });

            var idstodelete = ids.get();
            console.log(idstodelete);

            if (ids.length > 0) {
                // learn more: https://sweetalert2.github.io/
                swal.fire({
                    buttonsStyling: false,
                    text: "¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar los registros seleccionados?",
                    type: "danger",
                    confirmButtonText: "Si, eliminar!",
                    confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-sm btn-bold btn-danger",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    cancelButtonText: "No, cancelar",
                    cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-sm btn-bold btn-brand"
                }).then(function (result) {
                    if (result.value) {

                        $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            }
                        });

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/processes/offerdemand/delete',
                            data: { ids: idstodelete },
                            dataType: 'JSON',

                            success: function (data) {

                                var url = window.location.origin;
                                var link = '/processes/offerdemand';
                                var completeurl = url + link;

                                if (data.status != 200) {

                                    console.log(data.status);
                                    swal.fire({
                                        "title": "",
                                        "text": "Ocurrió un error, contactar al administrador",
                                        "type": "error",
                                        showConfirmButton: !1,
                                        timer: 2000,
                                        onClose: () => {
                                            window.location.href=completeurl
                                          }
                                    });

                                } else {
                                    swal.fire({
                                        "title": "",
                                        "text": "Se ha eliminado correctamente!",
                                        "type": "success",
                                        showConfirmButton: !1,
                                        timer: 2000,
                                        onClose: () => {
                                            window.location.href=completeurl
                                          }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        var xhr = $.ajax();
                        console.log(xhr)

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the exception:

```
{
"message": "Class 'App\OfferDemand' not found",
"exception": "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError",
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/app/Http/Controllers/OfferDemandController.php",
"line": 22,
"trace": [
{
"function": "delete",
"class": "App\Http\Controllers\OfferDemandController",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
"line": 54,
"function": "call_user_func_array"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
"line": 45,
"function": "callAction",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Controller",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
"line": 219,
"function": "dispatch",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
"line": 176,
"function": "runController",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Route",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
"line": 681,
"function": "run",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Route",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 130,
"function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
"line": 41,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
"line": 43,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php",
"line": 76,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
"line": 49,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
"line": 56,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
"line": 37,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
"line": 66,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 105,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
"line": 683,
"function": "then",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
"line": 658,
"function": "runRouteWithinStack",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
"line": 624,
"function": "runRoute",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
"line": 613,
"function": "dispatchToRoute",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
"line": 177,
"function": "dispatch",
"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 130,
"function": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/spatie/laravel-cors/src/Cors.php",
"line": 28,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Spatie\Cors\Cors",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
"line": 21,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
"line": 21,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
"line": 27,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
"line": 62,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
"line": 57,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 171,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
"line": 105,
"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
"line": 152,
"function": "then",
"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
"line": 117,
"function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "/opt/bitnami/apps/kiwidev/htdocs/kw-plataforma/public/index.php",
"line": 55,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel",
"type": "->"
}
]
}
```

This is the model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Offerdemand extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'prop_search_name',
        'prop_search_expiration',
        'prop_expired',
        'prop_transaction',
        'prop_type',
        'prop_currency',
        'prop_price_from',
        'prop_price_to',
        'email'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function offerdemandslocations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Offerdemandslocations::class);
    }

    public function offerdemandsattributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Offerdemandsattribute::class);
    }

    public function offerdemandsmatchs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Offerdemandsmatchs::class);
    }

    public function del_offermatches(){
        $this->offerdemandsmatchs()->delete();
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace Model Class name to OfferDemand from Offerdemand.

Comment: oh my god, so easy was that! Thanks @Yasir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using little 'd' in `Offerdemand` model class name, use `OfferDemand` instead.